# Accessing the request object with express-graphql

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql

According to

http://graphql.org/graphql-js/authentication-and-express-middleware/

> To use middleware with a GraphQL resolver, just use the middleware like you would with a normal Express app. The request object is then available as the second argument in any resolver.

However, when I run my resolver

```
module.exports = {
  Query: {
    books(root, args, context) {
      return books;
    }
  }
};
```

the second argument is my query arguments.  The third argument, however, unless I override the `context` config property to `expressGraphql` is indeed my request object.

My full config is

```
app.use(
  "/graphql",
  expressGraphql({
    schema,
    graphiql: true
  })
);
```

Are the docs wrong, or am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither :)

Even when building your schema with plain ole' GraphQL.js (as opposed to using `graphql-tools` or another library), there's a couple of different ways to pass in your resolvers.

You can generate it by creating a `GraphQLSchema` object, for example, in which case your resolvers are included within the `GraphQLObjectType`s you add to it. Here is a [repo](https://github.com/mrblueblue/graphql-express-sqlite) that does just that.

Alternatively, you can declare a schema using a string with `buildSchema`. You can see that being done [in the docs](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/running-an-express-graphql-server/). If you go this route, the only way to pass in your resolvers is to utilize the `rootValue` object passed into your endpoint configuration. Normally, the values parameters passed to your resolvers are

1. root
2. args
3. context
4. info

However, when you go the above route, you lose the first parameter... since I imagine we can't pass root to itself

It's a good illustration of why, if you're going to generate a schema declaratively, `graphql-tools` is the way to go.

Comment: Oh man thank you so much - this actually a few other points of confusion I had. So I was passing in my resolvers this way, from `graphql-tools`  https://github.com/arackaf/booklist/blob/feature/add-graphQL/schema.js#L16  Are you saying there's another route I could take, which does not have my schema as a string, and would affect my resolver args? So if someone goes that route, what _is_ the value of root? I can still specify it, docs mentioned "root resolver" but I didn't quite grok what that meant - I assumed it was for static global helpers or something :-P

Comment: I'm fairly sure the **only** time you'll see that first parameter drop is when you define your resolvers inside the `rootValue`. From what I understand, `rootValue` is a leftover from before `context` was available -- there's limited use for it nowadays... except if you choose to use `buildSchema`, in which case it's the only way you can pass in resolvers. [Example here](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/running-an-express-graphql-server/). If you're already using `graphql-tools`, you probably don't need to mess with rootValue.

Comment: Edited answer with a couple of example links.